opencv c++ not open .onnx file
I try to call:
cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX(":/yolo/yolov8n.onnx");

but it returns me:
OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:

OpenCV(4.5.5-dev) Error: Bad argument (Can't read ONNX file: :/yolo/yolov8n.onnx) in ONNXImporter, file C:\\Users\\m8317\\Downloads\\opencv_mingw\\opencv\\modules\\dnn\\src\\onnx\\onnx_importer.cpp, line 229

My code:
if(checkCameraAvailability())
    {
        QLabel *camera_goruntusu = findChild<QLabel*>("cameraLabel");

        cv::VideoCapture cap(0); // 0, ilk kamera cihazını temsil eder

        if (!cap.isOpened()) // Kamera başlatılamazsa
        {
            qDebug() << "Kamera açılamadı!";
            return;
        }

        // YOLOv8 modelini yükle
        cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX(":/yolo/yolov8n.onnx");

        while (true)
        {
            cv::Mat frame;
            cap >> frame; // Kameradan bir kare al
            if (frame.empty()) // Kare boşsa
            {
                qDebug() << "Kare alınamadı!";
                break;
            }



:/yolo/y.... is this missing the drive name? eg C:/yolo/y.... ?

that might be a valid windows path name, technically, i.e. nobody knows about this, so it's likely the source of the issue. it assumes the drive given in the CWD, but the specified absolute path on top of it. -- file might not be there, might be corrupted, ... we can't know. that's for OP to figure out.

[mre] required. strip all the Qt stuff out of it.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
